# How can I calculate the analytical derivative of a function?

Tags: python, differentiation

How can I analytically differentiate in Python?

E.g:

```
d/dx (x^3 * L * lambda /(pi*d))
```

---

Additional:
[image: Screenshot of an attempt to install sympy]

Comment: You could [use sympy](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorial/calculus.html#derivatives) for symbolic differentiation

Comment: Thank you for your fast response. I tryed the first example but the error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sympy' appears... 
Why is it so difficult to just simply calculate the derivative of a function...

Comment: I tryed: pip install sympy - but this doesnt work either.

Comment: Do you want the symbolic derivative or the numerical derivative (in which case scipy or numpy can be used to approximate)

Comment: simply the symbolic derivative

Comment: I only have RUN, TODO, Problems, Terminal, Pyhton Console. There is no command window

Comment: I write 'pip install sympy' in 'Python Console', the error 'Syntax Error: invalid syntax' occures

Comment: Ok. I unistalled all related python application.
Than i reinstalled python 3.9 from microsoft store and pycharm - community edition.
I opened IDLE Shell and wrote 'pip install sympy' - but i didnt worked. Message:Syntax Error:  'invalid syntax' appeard.
I opened python3.9.exe (I assume command window) and i tryed the same, but the same result.

Comment: Please note that your question is not about Pycharm. Pycharm is just a program helping you to write your code. Your question is about the programming language itself - Python

Comment: Please Google "How to install libraries in Python". As Cory told you a few times, this is not a Python command, it is a shell command that you're supposed to run in a terminal, not a Python console

Comment: I added a picture. The right blackish window is the command line...

Comment: [Install, uninstall, and upgrade packages](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/installing-uninstalling-and-upgrading-packages.html)

Comment: Thank you for you patience.
I got it, but starting with python is very confusing.

Comment: A good place to start is [The Python Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html). Stack Overflow is not really a place to learn, is a place to get help. Take your time and learn gradually starting from the basics and moving up. Working with advanced libraries when you still don't grasp the basics can surely be confusing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `sympy` to differentiate a function symbolically

```
>>> from sympy import *
>>> x, L, lamb, d = symbols('x L lamb d')
>>> f = x**3 * L * lamb / (pi * d)
>>> f
L*lamb*x**3/(pi*d)
>>> diff(f, x)
3*L*lamb*x**2/(pi*d)
```